# Duplicate GET requests being generated several seconds later in Chrome and Firefox by unknown user agent when a CGI script is invoked

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cgi

When I invoke a CGI script (GET request) using either Chrome or Firefox, I noticed in the Apache access log that quite a few seconds later a HEAD request and a GET request with the same URI were being generated.  To make sure it was not a peculiarity of my Apache setup, I wrote a simple Perl script and installed it on my ISP's website.  This script simply does it's own logging to a disk file every time it is invoked of the time, the URI, the user agent, the remote address and port:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use strict;
use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;
print $cgi->header(-type=>'text/plain', -expires=>'-1d');
print "hello";

open (LOG, ">>printenv2.txt");
my ($sec, $min, $hr, $day, $mon, $year) = localtime;
my $timestamp = sprintf("%02d/%02d/%04d %02d:%02d:%02d", $mon + 1, $day, 1900 + $year, $hr, $min, $sec);
print LOG $timestamp, "\n";
my @keys = qw(REQUEST_METHOD REQUEST_URI HTTP_USER_AGENT REMOTE_ADDR REMOTE_PORT);
foreach (@keys) {
    print LOG "$_ = $ENV{$_}\n";
}
print LOG "\n";
close LOG;
```

I invoked the script once with http://localhost/friends/forms/cgi/printenv2.cgi?arg=1

The script was run three times, however, the last two runs occurred more than 14 seconds after my initial invocation.  Here is the output of the log:

```
09/11/2015 19:25:26
REQUEST_METHOD = GET
REQUEST_URI = /friends/forms/cgi/printenv2.cgi?arg=1
HTTP_USER_AGENT = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
REMOTE_ADDR = 127.0.0.1
REMOTE_PORT = 58421

09/11/2015 19:25:40
REQUEST_METHOD = HEAD
REQUEST_URI = /friends/forms/cgi/printenv2.cgi?arg=1
HTTP_USER_AGENT = Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20150101 Firefox/20.0 (Chrome)
REMOTE_ADDR = 127.0.0.1
REMOTE_PORT = 58428

09/11/2015 19:25:41
REQUEST_METHOD = GET
REQUEST_URI = /friends/forms/cgi/printenv2.cgi?arg=1
HTTP_USER_AGENT = Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20150101 Firefox/20.0 (Chrome)
REMOTE_ADDR = 127.0.0.1
REMOTE_PORT = 58440
```

As you can see the user agent associated with the two spurious invocations is different.  I ran SpyHunter to see if I had a virus.  I tried disabling all extensions.  I tried un-installng and re-installing Chrome.  Nothing helps.  This only occurs with Chrome and Firefox - the problem does not appear with Internet Explorer.

HELP!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had tried doing a search on the complete user agent string and came up with nothing.  But I now decided to try again just searching on "Gecko/20150101" and came up with an article at: https://www.quppa.net/blog/2015/07/26/realplayerrealdownloader-poses-as-firefox-running-on-64-bit-linux-and-sends-head-and-get-requests/

I had installed the latest version of RealPlayer (now called RealTimes) and it had installed a Video Downloader.  This is *not* installed as an extension in Chrome and Firefox, but rather runs as a separate process.  I disabled this "addon" and now the spurious HEAD and GET requests seem to have disappeared.  What the hell were they thinking?

Comment: Thank you! You indirectly helped me. My site was being hammered with these duplicated requests. Seeing that the UA string is pretty much impossible to be found in the wild (Firefox *and* Chrome?) I just banned it at the server level and everything seems to be fine now :)

Comment: I was recently helping someone troubleshoot repeated blocks by Apache ModSecurity -- RealPlayer was sending HEAD and GET requests to a WordPress login page. It seemed to be hooking onto Google Chrome's web requests. They uninstalled it and the extra requests stopped. This solved the issue!

Comment: Just had this happen, was Realtimes